# Alguém consegue solucionar?

Tags: javascript

Alguém consegue solucionar esse problema? Gostaria de saber a resposta desse código! 
.
.
.
.
.

```
RegExp.name[5] + (undefined + '')[5] + 'x' + Number([]);
```

Comment: Boa tarde samu, tudo bem?
Então, você poderia ser mais especifico em que problema esta tendo?

Comment: Opa, tudo certo? gostaria de saber a resposta desse código.. oq ele retorna?

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a que melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101).

Answer (score 1):

Desejar aprender a programar é louvável, mas, se simplesmente deseja uma resposta para algum tipo de charada do amiguinho, aqui não é o lugar ideal.

Estou respondendo, considerando que você deseja aprender algo e não sabe exatamente por onde começar. Vai no próprio browser, inspecionar elementos e observe como as coisas acontecem e são feitas. Lá também tem um console que você pode executar funções javascript como esta.

Caso sua motivação seja outra, realmente estamos perdendo nosso tempo, o meu, o seu e o de mais alguém.

Não faz sentido sua pergunta. Mas, clique no executar e verá o que retorna:

```js
console.log( RegExp.name[5] + (undefined + '')[5] + 'x' + Number([]) );
```